# (Pandas) How to repeat item labels in pandas group by function?

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have the following data (df) :

[image]

I want to make a simple pivot (nested pivot like the following) where the labels are repeating like the yellow colored cells.

[image]

However, I am getting this

[image]

My code :

```
group_by = df.groupby(['meta_weight','meta_weight_type', 'weight_conversion'])['Sales_Unit'].sum()
print(group_by)
```

**Please tell me how can I repeat the labels, as we do it in pivot table in excel.**
Thank you

Comment: `However, I am getting this` - what is IDE for shown data this way? Because by default pandas only not shown repeated first level of duplicated values, but if write to excel data are written corectly.

Comment: Hi @jezrael: I am using the regular Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved by resetting index values

```
group_by_meta = df.groupby(['meta_weight','meta_weight_type', 'weight_conversion'])['Sales_Unit'].sum()
print(group_by_meta)

group_by_meta = group_by_meta.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem values are by default only not shown, so possible solution is turn off display this way:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
     print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, it got solved by resetting index values. Thank you so much for your time. :)